# PushView Navigation without reinitializing objects in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I just need to make navigation without reinitializing the objects, it can be done by popview Navigation but I need to navigate to the specified ViewController instead of previous view controller. I've posted another  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761233/popview-kind-of-navigation-ios) no response for that one still

Comment: What you have done or tried yet? Post your code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Interface Builder:

In the implementation (.m) file of the view controller you want to navigate back to, add this method:

```
-(IBAction)prepareForUnwind<NameOfViewController>:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

}
```

without the < >.  Then, on the Interface Builder for the view that you are trying to navigate from, you need to create an exit segue. If you have a cancel button, you can ctrl + drag to the little orange exit symbol at the very top of your view controller, then release and select the prepareForUnwind method you created.  If you do not have a button that specifically makes you go backwards, and you want to do this programmatically, you could ctrl + drag from the yellow icon at the top of your view controller to the orange exit icon, select the unwind method, then look at the view hierarchy for the segue you just created.  Click it, then go to the attribute inspector and change the identifier.  Then, in the implementation file for the view controller you are navigating from, call this method:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"whateverYouNamedIt" sender:self];
```

An unwind segue like this goes backwards through your stack until it finds a view controller that has the unwind method that you called, then pops all view controllers in between that one and your current view controller.  You could have a `prepareForUnwind<NameOfViewController>` method on every view controller, and use that to go backwards. It makes the storyboard look a lot cleaner, since unwind segues don't show up other than in the view hierarchy.

edit - Just wanted to add that if you want to pass any information from the source view controller to the destination view controller, you do that inside of the prepareForUnwindSegue method in the destination view controller, much like you'd use prepareForSegue method in a source view controller moving forward.  Here's an example:

```
-(IBAction)PrepareForUnwindHome:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    OtherViewController *sourceView = segue.sourceViewController;
    _NSStringVariable = sourceView.NSStringVariable;
}
```

That'll set the NSStringVariable on the previous view controller that you are navigating back to to the NSStringVariable from the source view controller that you are navigating from.